# Spring mvc controller test + Json response error

Tags: spring, testing, spring-mvc

I have in my spring mvc test controller:

```
@Test
public void consultaPorIdJson() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(get("/timesheet/consultaporidjson/{id}", 1L))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(TestSupport.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(content().string("{\"id\":1,\"latitude\":\"30.448660206791608\",\"longitude\":\"-44.29684999999995\"}"));
```

When I trying to run my test I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set error status - response is already committed
```

I think that is about 2k (I think) of response, but I don't know what must I do to fix it :-(

Answer (score 0):

Does the url works outside of your test? I doubt it does not work as the error suggests you have issue in your implementation where the code is trying to change the status when something is already written in the response.

Comment: I didn't try run out of my test because I didn't do jsp. I'm bulding without jsp, I put only REST. When I tried returning only "new MyClass()" in my controller, the test ran without problem. But when I return my object full, I have this problem.

Comment: No need for jsp. Its a rest url so simply type that in the browser or use postman. Also if you show your controller code then that would help.